# How can I extract a line containing a specific date using Sequalize?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have created the following database table:

[image: database table]

I would like to extract only the line 2017-08-29 using Sequalize.

How can it be realized?

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        dateTime: ...,
    }
})
```

Both the date and time are registered in the database table I created, but I would like to extract the rows only by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        dateTime: {$eq: new Date(2017, 07, 29)}
    }
})
```

Note:

> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether it is the best method, but I did it like this.

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        dateTime: {$between: [new Date(2017,07,29,00,00), new Date(2017,07,29,24,00)]}
    }
});
```

Thank you for telling me Xiaoy 312.

Comment: You might want to change the upper bound to `new Date(new Date(2017, 07, 30) - 1)` or `new Date(2017, 07, 29, 23, 59, 59, 999)` to avoid some extremely rare edge case.